# POST calls with Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I've been struggling a bit with implementing a POST call to an ASP.NET API with Ionic 2. I managed a GET with the help of a useful guide, but I couldn't really find anything similar for POST, until I came across a YouTube video. With the help of that video, I have this method in my provider:

```
 backendlogin() {
  if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
      var json = JSON.stringify({ email: 'a@hotmail.com', password: 'root' });
      var params = 'json=' + json;
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      this.http.post('http://insertipadresshere/api/login',
          params, {
              headers: headers
          })
          .map(res => res.json())
          .subscribe(data => {
              this.data = data;
              resolve(this.data);
          },
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log("Finished")
      );
  });
}
```

My GET methods are basically what was provided by Ionic when creating the provider. They are similar to this code, except for the part where the variables are declared and the headers are appended, as well as http.get instead of post of course.

This is the function I use to call the function of the provider from the controller of the page:

```
setuplogin() {
    this.backend.backendlogin()
        .then(data => {
            this.data = data;
        });
    console.log(this.data);
}
```

Now on to the issue. If I understand everything, backendLogin() should display an alert with the error if something fails, which it does. The alert says "[object Object]". The only thing in the console is an empty log, presumably from setupLogin() because data is empty. The api should take an email adress and a password and return a uID. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would reject the promise if there is an error:

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  var json = JSON.stringify({ email: 'a@hotmail.com', password: 'root'});
  var params = 'json=' + json;
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  this.http.post('http://insertipadresshere/api/login',
      params, {
          headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
      },
      error => reject(error),
      () => console.log("Finished")
  );
});
```

That said, I don't think that it's necessary to create a raw promise. You leverage the `toPromise` method of observables:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ email: 'a@hotmail.com', password: 'root'});
var params = 'json=' + json;
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post('http://insertipadresshere/api/login',
      params, {
          headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise();
);
```

Get the error

```
setuplogin() {
  this.backend.backendlogin()
    .then(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
    }, error => {
      // do something
    });
}
```

To finish, you could directly use the observable rather than returning a promise:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({ email: 'a@hotmail.com', password: 'root'});
var params = 'json=' + json;
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

return this.http.post('http://insertipadresshere/api/login',
      params, {
          headers: headers
      })
      .map(res => res.json());
);
```

and subscribe on it in the `setupLogin` method:

```
setuplogin() {
  this.backend.backendlogin()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
    },
setuplogin() {
  this.backend.backendlogin()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
    }, error => {
        // do something with error
    });
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately. Do you think it's an issue with the API? I haven't written the code for that myself, but I can contact the author.

Comment: Can you see the request that is actually executed in dev tools, network tab? Could be helpful to have a look at it ;-)

Comment: I can, what data do you need? I notice there's a 400 Bad Request for the POST method.

Comment: Found out that the issue was the 'json=' part of the params variable. Thanks for pointing me to the network tab, kinda forgot it existed.