# What is the correct way to access data from local storage and send to server in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-services, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to get my token from local storage and set it in header, but I don't know why it is not setting.

```
 getMurals() {
        return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/murals', this.getHeader())
          .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

private getHeader() {
    let header = new Headers();
    this.storage.get('token').then((token)=>{
      if(token){
        header.append('authorization',token);
        header.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      }
    })
    return new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your`header` is not yet prepared, because it is waiting to get `storage` promise to get resolved. When you call `return new RequestOptions({ headers: header });`, the `header is not prepared`. The flow is

1. let header = new Headers();
2. Waiting for storage to resolve token. Not yet completed and still proceeds to 3.
3. return new RequestOptions({ headers: header });

You can return promise. Like this:

```
getMurals() {
    this.getHeader().then(data => {
      return this.http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT+'/murals', data)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    })
}

private getHeader() {
    let header = new Headers();
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.storage.get('token').then((token)=>{
        if(token){
          header.append('authorization',token);
          header.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        resolve(new RequestOptions({ headers: header }));
      });
    });
}
```

Also, there is a lot of error handling to do here in case of errors. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163170/post-calls-with-ionic-2) for more clarity.

NOTE: This can also be done via creating an observable. You can do that using `Observable.create(observer => { observer.next(new RequestOptions({headers: header})); })`.